# Generate Result based on max count in secondary column after a join

Tags: sql, oracle, join, plsql, full-outer-join

I have two tables which have a common key between them, and quite a lot of other important infos ; for the sake of simplicity i will be using Combination A and Combination B. When a combination is met, whichever table has the maximum number of records should be the source where i collect the information ; in this case say IDs. The priority when counts are same is Table1.

COMMONKEY column is the combination/join condition in my tables.

```
    (Table 1)

  SELECT '123' table1_id,'Comb A' commonkey from dual UNION
  SELECT '124' table1_id,'Comb A' commonkey from dual UNION
  SELECT '125' table1_id,'Comb A' commonkey from dual UNION
  SELECT '126' table1_id,'Comb A' commonkey from dual UNION
  SELECT '215' table1_id,'Comb B' commonkey from dual UNION
  SELECT '216' table1_id,'Comb B' commonkey from dual UNION
  SELECT '559' table1_id,'Random Combination 1' commonkey from dual UNION
  SELECT '560' table1_id,'Random Combination 2' commonkey from dual ;   
                                 
    ( Table 2 )     
        
  SELECT 'abc1' table2_id,'Comb A' commonkey from dual  UNION
  SELECT 'abc2' table2_id,'Comb A' commonkey from dual  UNION
  SELECT 'abc3' table2_id,'Comb A' commonkey from dual  UNION
  SELECT 'abc4' table2_id,'Comb A' commonkey from dual  UNION
  SELECT 'xyz1' table2_id,'Comb B' commonkey from dual  UNION
  SELECT 'xyz2' table2_id,'Comb B' commonkey from dual  UNION
  SELECT 'xyz3' table2_id,'Comb B' commonkey from dual  UNION
  SELECT 'xyz2' table2_id,'Comb B' commonkey from dual  UNION 
  SELECT '416abc1' table2_id,'Random Combination 91' commonkey from dual UNION
  SELECT '416abc2' table2_id,'Random Combination 92' commonkey from dual;
  
    
    

Result Set Expected :

ID        COMMONKEY         
123       Comb A            
124       Comb A            
125       Comb A            
126       Comb A            
xyz1      Comb B            
xyz2      Comb B            
xyz3      Comb B            
559       Random Combination 1          
560       Random Combination 1          
416abc1   Random Combination 91         
416abc2   Random Combination 92
```

[Updated Image :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVXgH.png)

( the image shows a screenshot of the trail data in an excel; The Requirement and Strategy are color mapped to make it quickly understandable )

I need to generate the result set using SQL as follows :

When table1.commonkey = table2.commonkey hits, I need to-

- If table1 has 10 IDs, table2 has 5 IDs -> Pick 10 IDs from table1.
- If table1 has 15 IDs, table2 has 30 IDs -> Pick 30 IDs from table2.
- If table1 has 4 IDs, table2 has 4 IDs -> Pick 4 IDs from table1.
  ( when equal, choose table1 IDs )
- When no matches occur with the common key, prevent a cross join and add in the rowsets linearly to the result table.

Edit : I've initially gone on routes with

```
  a left join b where b.key IS null ;
  a full outer join b where b.key IS NULL or a.key is NULL ;
```

to achieve workarounds with A-B or B-A result sets but both these approaches were quite wrong. Gathering Delta sets or Exclusion sets didnt go well.

Comment: Better but now an image is redundant. Also you don't say what the link links to. PS Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. (Obligatory for debug questions.) [ask] [Help] For non-code see editor help re table format (with a lot of unnecessary whitespace but other benefits).

Comment: Please show what you can do in questions. Research is expected. Please don't ask us to write your code.

Comment: Better but: When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by authoritative documentation. Give a [mre] with the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) Don't just give up & dump undebugged code & ask us to write correct code, or ask us to rewrite a manual re the functionality you used while guessing at what you already don't understand. PS We can't cut & paste & run those tables.

Comment: Understood, sorry about that, will include my attempts as well. I simply didnt want to write them as they were very wrong approaches.

Comment: Ask 1 (specific researched non-duplicate) question per post. Either about a bug or about being stuck finding good code while giving parts that work; not both. Don't invalidate reasonable posted answers via edits. PS After a [mre] pins down a problem it's likley a faq. Please before considering posting read the manual & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. Reflect your research.  If you post a question, use one phrasing as title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one option; see comments within code

```
SQL> with
  2  -- sample data
  3  a (id, ckey) as
  4    (select '123', 'ca' from dual union all
  5     select '124', 'ca' from dual union all
  6     select '125', 'ca' from dual union all
  7     select '126', 'ca' from dual union all
  8     select '215', 'cb' from dual union all
  9     select '216', 'cb' from dual union all
 10     select '551', 'r1' from dual union all
 11     select '552', 'r2' from dual
 12    ),
 13  b (id, ckey) as
 14    (select 'abc1', 'ca' from dual union all
 15     select 'abc2', 'ca' from dual union all
 16     select 'abc3', 'ca' from dual union all
 17     select 'abc4', 'ca' from dual union all
 18     select 'xyz1', 'cb' from dual union all
 19     select 'xyz2', 'cb' from dual union all
 20     select 'xyz3', 'cb' from dual union all
 21     select '9991', 'r3' from dual union all
 22     select '9992', 'r4' from dual
 23    ),
```

---

```
 24  -- count rows per each CKEY (common key)
 25  tempa as
 26    (select id, ckey, count(*) over (partition by ckey) cnt
 27     from a
 28    ),
 29  tempb as
 30    (select id, ckey, count(*) over (partition by ckey) cnt
 31     from b
 32    )
 33  -- final query
 34  select distinct
 35    case when a.cnt >= b.cnt then a.id
 36         else b.id
 37    end id,
 38    a.ckey
 39  from tempa a join tempb b on b.ckey = a.ckey
 40  union all
 41  select ckey, id from a
 42    where not exists (select null from b where a.ckey = b.ckey)
 43  union all
 44  select ckey, id from b
 45    where not exists (select null from a where a.ckey = b.ckey)
 46  order by 1, 2;
```

which results in

```
ID   CKEY
---- -----
r1   551
r2   552
r3   9991
r4   9992
xyz1 cb
xyz2 cb
xyz3 cb
123  ca
124  ca
125  ca
126  ca

11 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you :) I was quite lost as this common key was over multiple columns and the datasets had lots of unpivoting and transformations. I'll implement this and observe my data. 

Sorry for the edit but could you give me an insight on how i can handle this when Common keys *dont* match. I would want to prevent a cross join. And add them up in the result set in a linear way.

Comment: You're welcome. And you don't need cross join; two UNIONs would do the job. Edited, have a look.